# I'm wondering about custom attributes, CSS attribute selector & repaint

Tags: css, reactjs

So a little disclaimer: I am completely and utterly self taught. Bear over with me if I'm being a clown.

Anyways, I am currently working on a some platform and in need for a dropdown functionality. That's simple right? Just use HTML5 select tag. However option tags can't be styled :>

So onwards to build my own. The HTML5 select tag uses keyboard input (up/down/enter) for those with disabilities, and I thought I would implement that too. That did present a problem though: The `:hover` selector collided with my custom attribute, which I use to style keyboard selected items (`&[data-selected=true]` to be precise).

So onwards to implement my own `:hover`. And this is where my bewilderment starts.

```
const handleChildMouseOver = () => {
  const items = Array.from(listItem.current?.children!); // The wonders of typescript XD

  for (const item of items) {
    if (item === event.target) {
      item.setAttribute("data-selected", "true");
    } else {
      item.removeAttribute("data-selected"); // I'm removing the attribute, rather than toggling it, because I got components with 3 states: On, off, and default.
    }
  }
}
(...)
<ul css={css.list} /*emotion prop*/ data-toggled={toggled} /*parent state*/ onMouseOver={handleChildMouseOver}>
  {children} // parent prop
</ul>
```

So it works as intended, which is fine. But I recall from my pre-react days that you should never manipulate the DOM in loops, as it causes repaints on every iteration. However when I look at the Dev Tools performance profiler, I barely see any "Paints", 8 or so, even when I'm switching hover targets like a madman. What I do see is one million "Composite layer". Oh, and as a bonus React doesn't re-render. Which is fine right? 'Cause I'm not really changing the state of anything, just adding some CSS.

**So my question boils down to**: Am I being bonkers or smart?

N.B.: I would love to share the actual component, but seeing as this is my first post on stackoverflow, I've got no clue how you do those fancy script tag. Well github is involved somehow, I know that much